# Why do I see OOMs in my spark job, when total input size increases but per task input size stays the same?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a spark job which is given an input already divided into partitions of size 10 MB each.

When I run this spark job with small total input size, I don't see any Out of Memory (OOM), but when I run this spark job with big total input size, I see OOMs.

In both cases, executors are allocated the same amount of memory. In both cases, there are 2 cores per executor. In both cases, each task is given the same size of input as it is divided into partitions of size 10 MB.

Do you have any idea why I see OOMs, when I run this job with a big total input size?

Comment: how do you know that 1 partition has only 10mb each?

Comment: if its big data how many partitions and small data how many partitions you have ?  OOM stacktrace also needed? better to mention spark version you are using with sample code snippet